# Are both oven doors identical in a double oven?

Tags: electrical, oven

KitchenAid double oven model KEBC207KBT03  "Door open" message will not clear - preventing oven from heating - also both interior oven lights stay on. I have replaced door latch assembly and sister board but does not solve the problem

Comment: Does the door latch contain the switch/sensor for door open?

Comment: door latch has a switch, you can identify by looking for wires. After you found the wires (2 of them) create a bridge (connect them together, to force the door close signal. This is only temporary just to find out if the door switch is working

Comment: Why is the title about doors being identical? I don't see what that has to do with the problem. The problem sounds more like "Why does my oven say the doors are open when they are not?" In any case, it is normal (for decades) for a Kitchenaid double-oven to turn on both lights when you open either door - just simpler that way - one override button in the control panel and the two door switches all "or" together with respect to "all lights".

Comment: Lights on both ovens all the time but I am not so worried about that as I am with - When I click on start for the upper oven to proceed with heat I get a flashing message "Close Door". The door latch has 2 micro switches - I have bridged them both but the close door message remains the same. (ps I have installed a new door latch assembly and sister board but the problem stays the same.